# Как получить количество пользователей в беседе вк через json массив

Tags: php

Есть у меня json массив `{ "response":[ { "first_name":"Степан", "id":309718232, "last_name":"Росляков'", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Макс", "id":551838006, "last_name":"Фокстер", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Lorenzo", "id":531142519, "last_name":"Duble", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Михаил", "id":496671203, "last_name":"Краснокутский", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Вадим", "id":326034787, "last_name":"Кравченко", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Матвей", "id":538170066, "last_name":"Захаров", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Кирилл", "id":455574835, "last_name":"Говоров", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Mike", "id":622764335, "last_name":"Moki", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Егор", "id":517942047, "last_name":"Серов", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Егор", "id":562580163, "last_name":"Иванов", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Саламон", "id":610730563, "last_name":"Десперальдо", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Илья", "id":504055304, "last_name":"Левашов", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Макс", "id":580032345, "last_name":"Царевский", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Sergey", "id":267812132, "last_name":"Makarov", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Эльдор", "id":631723758, "last_name":"Самп", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Sergey", "id":436342794, "last_name":"Pomazan", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Рома", "id":334153686, "last_name":"Клименко", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Марк", "id":532965594, "last_name":"Макиев", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Владислав", "id":404740223, "last_name":"Тимофеев", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Ярослав'халиф", "id":307875074, "last_name":"Драгонов", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Богдан", "id":407294287, "last_name":"Кустуров", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "first_name":"Арбалай", "id":607614289, "last_name":"Жамахов", "nickname":"", "can_invite_to_chats":false, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"profile" }, { "name":"SAMP: Tumple RolePlay | Официальное сообщество", "id":174327796, "invited_by":-174327796, "type":"group" }, { "name":"Conference Manager", "id":178513588, "invited_by":531142519, "type":"group" } ] }`, нужно из этого массива получить количество пользователей, пытался `count($data[response])` выводило 1. Можете помоч?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно распарсить json

```
$response = json_decode($data, true);
```

А после

```
count($response['response']))
```